# How do I pull a value next to another value in a text file

Tags: python, date, full-text-search, txt

I used an excel file and equation to list a few hundred dates that a week ends on, and there is a specific invoice number that should ascociate with each date. I converted it to a txt file so the entries look like this:

```
1001,09/26/20,
1002,10/03/20,
1003,10/10/20,
1004,10/17/20,
1005,10/24/20,
```

I would like to be able to search the file for the date entry, then find the corresponding invoice number located to its left. If it is easier to search and get the value, it would be easy to change the invoice numbers to be on the right side.

This is the code I drafted to format the date into the format used in the text file, then search for it. I have no idea what to write for what happens after.

```
# declare the correct formatted date to search the file for
    date_search_formatted = date_input.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    # open the text file
    file = open(r"Invoice_doc_01.txt", "r")
    # read the text file
    file.read()
    # search for the string
    file.find(date_search_formatted)
    
    # save the text file
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary:

```
import csv


csv_string="""1001,09/26/20, 
1002,10/03/20, 
1003,10/10/20, 
1004,10/17/20, 
1005,10/24/20,
"""

lines = csv_string.splitlines()
reader = csv.reader(lines)

inv = {}
for line in reader:
    inv[line[0]] = line[1]
    
for k, v in inv.items():
    print(k, v)
    # search for e.g.
    if k == '1003':
        print(f"Invoice no {k} from {v}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file is actually a CSV, you can use the csv reader to load it and continue from that.

As a sidemark, it is good practice to use the `with` statement, when opening files.